# Porque não está a comparar?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, login

Tenho este código para comparar o email e a palavra passe que estão na base de dados, mas dá sempre que os dados estão errados, não deixando entrar. O que há de errado com o código, podem me ajudar?

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "isabelso_isabel";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "isabelso_db";


$dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($conn));;


//Get user details and put them on varaiables
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['login']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $_POST['senha']);

        if (!empty($email) && !empty($password))
        {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Paciente WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($data);
        printf("Number of rows %d \n", $result);
        if ($result == 1) {

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
            $email = $row('login');
            $password = $row('senha');
            header("location: marcar_consulta_online.html");
        } else {

            echo  "<script>alert('A password e/ou email est達o erradas');</script>";
        }

        }
        else
        {

            echo  "<script>alert('Deve preencher com o seu email e password);</script>";
            ?>

        <?php
        }
        mysqli_close($dbcon);
        ?>
```

Comment: $result = mysqli_num_rows($data);

Comment: esse tipo de erro não merece uma resposta, basta um comentário

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho que o código não está a funcionar devido a estas linhas.

```
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($dbname);
```

Pois estas a buscar a linha de **$dbname** não de **$data**,assim o programa nunca chega a comparar, logo devia ser assim:

```
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);
```

Tudo de bom

Comment: Já comparou... Mas por  exemplo, quando assume que os dados são iguais deveria abrir outro ficheiro... Esta linha não faria isso? header("location: marcar_consulta_online.html");

Comment: Sim, ela faria mas provavelmente o programa está a falhar na linha $email = $row('login');
            $password = $row('senha'); deveriam  ser usados [] em vez de ()

Answer (score 0):

Opa.

 `$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($dbname);`

Você passou o dbname no lugar do $data ai o php não sabe da onde pegar a quantidade de linhas, por isso seu código está só dando erro. o certo seria:

 `$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($data);`